# What's the meaning of the "set -o emacs" command?

Tags: bash, emacs

What's the meaning, or what does the following do?

```
set -o emacs
```

I saw it somewhere, and I am an Emacs user, so it makes me curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`set -o emacs` tells the [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) to understand Emacs editing commands.

That is, you can use Emacs commands at your shell prompt and they will work as expected. For example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> deletes a line.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> transposes two chars.
- <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> deletes a word.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> goes to the previous line, that is, the previous command.

(More commands [here](http://lpn.rnbhq.org/tools/xemacs/emacs_ref.html), note that not all will work because not all make sense at the command line.)

`set -o emacs` works with `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`, [the default shell starting with macOS 10.15 Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050). Other Bourne-based shells may include this functionality, too.

For `bash` and `zsh`, `emacs` is the default editing mode. You can also choose `vi` mode with `set -o vi` (in this case, you will probably want to set Option as the Meta key in the Keyboard tab of your Terminal profile).

Comment: Can't find Meta+P, only Meta+D to delete a word in the [Readline Killing Commands (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Killing-Commands.html).